# entry.get() function won't change value of a variable

Tags: python, function, tkinter, label

I have some code which asks the user to enter a word they'd like to encrypt and then the program will encrypt the word and display it on a label.
I was wondering why the following code works:

```
import tkinter

letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

encryption_code = 'LFWOAYUISVKMNXPBDCRJTQEGHZ'
letters += letters.lower()
encryption_code += encryption_code.lower()

window = tkinter.Tk()
encryption_code_entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry = tkinter.Entry(window)

enc = dict(zip(letters,encryption_code))

string = 'hello world'

encr = "".join([enc.get(ch, ch) for ch in string])

def encrypt():    
    encrypt_label.pack()
    entry.pack()
    encrypt_confirm.pack()
    encrypt_button.destroy()

def display_encrypt():
    display_enc = encr
    encrypted_label.pack()
    new_message.config(text=str(display_enc))
    new_message.pack()

encrypt_confirm = tkinter.Button(window, text="Confirm", command=display_encrypt)
new_message = tkinter.Label(window, text="", font=('Helvetica', 10))
encrypted_label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Your message " + entry.get() + " has been encrypted into the following: ")
encrypt_button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Encrypt", command=encrypt)
encrypt_button.pack()
encrypt_label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Please enter the message you'd like to encrypt", font=('Helvetica', 14))

window.mainloop()
```

But if I change `string = 'hello world'` (which is what I'd like to do) to `string = entry.get()` nothing is displayed`on`new_message`. Also,

```
encrypted_label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Your message " + entry.get() + "has been encrypted into the following: ")
```

doesn't display what the user typed in the entry box so I'm almost 100% sure I'm misusing the `entry.get()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You in fact need to have the `entry.get()` under `display_encrypt()`.

Every time the `encrypt_confirm` button is pressed, it calls `display_encrypt` which will then in turn be able to get the current string in `entry` every time it is pressed by the user.

I edited your code a bit and it seems to be working.

Notice that I have removed `string` and `encr` as they were now redundant variables.

```
import tkinter

letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

encryption_code = 'LFWOAYUISVKMNXPBDCRJTQEGHZ'
letters += letters.lower()
encryption_code += encryption_code.lower()

window = tkinter.Tk()
encryption_code_entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry = tkinter.Entry(window)

enc = dict(zip(letters,encryption_code))

string = 'hello world'

def encrypt():    
    encrypt_label.pack()
    entry.pack()
    encrypt_confirm.pack()
    encrypt_button.destroy()

def display_encrypt():
    display_enc = "".join([enc.get(ch, ch) for ch in entry.get()])
    encrypted_label.pack()
    new_message.config(text=str(display_enc))
    new_message.pack()

encrypt_confirm = tkinter.Button(window, text="Confirm", command=display_encrypt)
new_message = tkinter.Label(window, text="", font=('Helvetica', 10))
encrypted_label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Your message " + entry.get() + " has been encrypted into the following: ")
encrypt_button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Encrypt", command=encrypt)
encrypt_button.pack()
encrypt_label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Please enter the message you'd like to encrypt", font=('Helvetica', 14))

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `entry.get()` well before the user ever has a chance to enter anything. You need to call it and reset the label in response to an event, such as the user pressing <Return>, clicking a button, etc.

Comment: Would it work if I just put `entry.get()` under the `def display_encrypt()`?